# How to create a file in public folder according to environnement

Tags: nuxt.js, applinks

I would like to add a different [app-links.json](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) to the root of my project according to my NODE_ENV

I didn't see anything about adding a specific file to `public` folder in `nuxt-config.js`

---

For example I want to have my `app-links.json` at the root of my project to be

**In production**

```json
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "...PRODUCTION...",
  }
}]
```

**And in staging**

```json
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "...STAGING...",
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained something similar into one of my previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689890/8816585

Use `fs.writeFile` at the top of your `nuxt.config.js` file to write a file depending of your env.

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  fs.writeFile(...production)
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
  fs.writeFile(...staging)
}
```

That way, every time you build your project, it will check the env variable related to your env and create the proper file.

You can try this locally with `NODE_ENV=production yarn generate` (or `NODE_ENV=production yarn build` in case your target is `server`).