# How to access data from firestore write it into a file during Nuxt build?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

**I'm trying to do this in the head from `nuxt.config.js`:**
and create json file in the folder lang

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import { db } from '../GUILLERMO-QUINTERO-ROJAS/services/firebase'
db.collection('english').doc('english').get().then((response) => {
  fs.writeFile('lang/todos_1.json', JSON.stringify(response.data(), null, 2), 'utf-8', (err) => {
    if (err) return console.log('An error happened', err)
    console.log('File fetched from {JSON} Placeholder and written locally!')
  })
})
```

**I followed this example who works perfectly with axios request**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689890/16899587

It's showing me this erros:

[image: visualcode]

[image: browser]

Or when I tried with this:

[image: wrote own module]

Comment: Hi, do what is not working there? Any errors/issues? Does it work in a regular `.vue` file?

Comment: Nothing, not erros, it's not showing me something weird. I tried to do in another vue file but I can't `import fs from 'fs'` `This dependency was not found:` I tried with `npm install --save fs` But It's not working, any suggestions ?

Comment: Now I added the pictures with the errors

Comment: wrong place to put code, instead make a build module https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules i.e `module.exports = function writeLang(options) {
  this.nuxt.hook('build:done', (builder) => {// your code here})}`

Comment: when I tried with this example works perfect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689890/16899587
but when I used my frirebase request  didn't work

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Comment: I added the pictures in the question, I think I'm having problems with the firebase request, it's not working here in the nuxtconfig.js... the two pic of that are in the question "It's showing me this erros:"

"missing or insuficient permisions" and `err_incomplete_chunked_encoding`

Comment: `missing or insuficient permisions` is the one. The rest is probably unrelated IMO.

Comment: Mmm it's like I can't use the firebase request in the nuxtconfig, mabe I can try in a vue file. But always said when I tried to import the `fs` this: `This dependency was not found:`  I can't use `fs.writeFile()` inside of a funtion in a vue file ?

Comment: Okay I got it, thanks guys for the time, my problem was with the auth with firebase. So I log-in then I did the rest

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this code inside of the `nuxtconfig.js` and **this worked**
**But I'm not sure is the best place and the best way to do, maybe you can give another ideas**

```js
hooks: {
  build: {
    done(builder) {
      builder.nuxt.options.buildDir
      const account = {
        email: process.env.NUXT_ENV_FIREBASE_EMAIL,
        password: process.env.NUXT_ENV_FIREBASE_PASSWORD
      }
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(account.email, account.password).then(() => {
        db.collection('english').doc('english').get().then((response) => {
          fs.writeFile('lang/prueba.json', JSON.stringify(response.data(), null, 2), 'utf-8', (err) => {
            if (err) return console.log('An error happened', err)
            console.log('File fetched from {JSON} Placeholder and written locally!')
          })
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

JSON file in the lang folder

[image: json file in the lang folder]

Comment: Looks nice to me.

Comment: this function will only be executed once?  @kissu
I mean if I finished my app and I hosted, this function is not going to update the new data to the json file

Comment: You can check the [details here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-hooks#list-of-hooks), it depends of your configuration I'd say. But yeah, as you can guess you need to rebuild your app if using SSG to get the info updated.

Answer (score 0):

OP needed to login first before using the rest of firebase's functions.